# IN clause not working correctly in two tables

Tags: mysql

I have a query regarding IN clause that I am trying to use and getting weird result .

I have two tables as below :

[image: Table-Topics]

[image: Table- Cat]

Query 1-

```
select topic_cat from Topics ;
```

giving result as expected `1,2,3,4,5`;

Query 2-

```
select cat_name 
from Cat 
where cat_id in(1,2,3,4,5);
```

giving result as expected `cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5`

Query 3-

```
select cat_name 
from Cat,Topics 
where cat_id in(topic_cat)
```

I am getting `cat1` as the result of above query where as I expect the result to be `cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5`

What is wrong in my understanding for IN Clause ?

Comment: your schema need to be changed in that case

Comment: Your query 3 is like doing `WHERE cat_id IN ('1,2,3,4,5')`. The quotes make it a single string, not a list of 5 different numbers.